# Electric shock when touching insulated plug

Tags: plug, shock

Something weird happened.

My girlfriend tried to unplug our dryer from the wall outlet. We live in Germany.

She touched the plug on the insulation (like normal) and did not touch the pins, but still got a painful electric shock.

She says she leaned over the dryer to unplug, so maybe the issue is with the dryer having current on the outside of the dryer body, or the wall outlet has an issue.

But can it be an electrostatic shock? It seems weird because she got the shock when she touched the insulated part (she even didn't remove the plug, she just touched the plug right before.)

Just want to know if this is something we should watch out for health wise.

Comment: There's really not enough information. The isolation on the plug might be damaged. There might be a ground fault in the dryer. If it's an older house there might not be a RCD... etc...

Comment: Yeah, old house. Possibly no RCD. I am not electrical expert, hence the post here in this forum ;)

Comment: Just want to evaluate if this was something harmful to my girlfriend or something I should go see a doctor..

Comment: If she's feeling fine it's most likely OK. I've been shocked countless times and I'm still here. I'd have the outlet and device in question inspected by someone knowledgeable tough.

Comment: Is the socket on the wall with 3 contacts (schuko?) and does the dryer have matching 3 contact plug?

Comment: Your girlfriend is probably fine; electric shock doesn't generally have long-term effects that aren't immediately noticeable. Your dryer and house/apartment wiring, on the other hand, may not be fine. They might need some repair to prevent more serious problems in the future! I'd recommend getting an electrician to take a look if you can.

Comment: You ask if it could be ESD. ESD can be distinguished from a mains electric shock by the very short duration of it. When you receive an ESD shock, it happens just at the moment you touch something, in fact, often the shock occurs when your hand is a mm or two away from touch. A shock from mains will ONLY occur when you have firm contact with the conductor, and will last as long as the contact remains. A shock from mains will likely be very repeatable. ESD shocks are most likely and most severe when the air is dry.

Comment: @Justme: Yeah, both schuko (3 contacts).

Comment: Electrostatic charge is typically generated when dissimilar materials are rubbed together in a dry environment, so a tumble dryer is an ideal source.  However, the dryer metalwork and any exposed metal on the plug *should* be earthed (and connected to each other).  So touching the dryer and the plug at the same time should be fine, but reaching into the dryer to remove (charged) items and then touching an earthed metal part would likely cause a painful but harmless ESD shock.

Comment: If the ground contact has a failure, most 3 contact devices have a mains filter which will capacitively couple half mains AC voltage to metal chassis. You could have a broken ground wire at some point, so touching both the dryer and something that is grounded would feel unpleasant. Try to figure out what items were touched when that happened, if the plug is not suspicious then perhaps leaning on dryer or coming in contact with metal pipes etc could explain something.